# Automation of Close, Maximize, Minimize Button in Fluent(Codeplex) Ribbon - WPF Application

Tags: wpf, automation, coded-ui-tests, ribbon, fluent-ribbon

I am trying to Automate the fluent Ribbon Controls (www.fluent.codeplex.com).  I am successful in automating most of the controls. But there is an issue like Close, Maximize and Minimize Buttons are not recognized or identified by UI Automation Tool, for example, Coded UI Test using Visual Studio. The Spy tool doesn't identify close, maximize, minimize, etc button. I am not able to close the application (which uses fluent Ribbon) through Automation.

I was looking at the following section of code in RibbonWindow.xaml

```
<StackPanel x:Name="PART_ButtonsPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,8,8,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Button x:Name="minimizeButton" Style="{DynamicResource CaptionButtonStyle}" Width="35" Height="19" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" Command="{x:Static Fluent:RibbonWindow.MinimizeCommand}">
            <Image Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" Source="{DynamicResource ImageCaptionButtonMinimize}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
          </Button>
          <Button x:Name="maximizeButton" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource CaptionButtonStyle}" Width="35" Height="19" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Command="{x:Static Fluent:RibbonWindow.MaximizeCommand}">
            <Image Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" Source="{DynamicResource ImageCaptionButtonMaximize}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
          </Button>
          <Button x:Name="normalizeButton" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource CaptionButtonStyle}" Width="35" Height="19" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Command="{x:Static Fluent:RibbonWindow.NormalizeCommand}">
            <Image Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" Source="{DynamicResource ImageCaptionButtonNormalize}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
          </Button>
          <Button x:Name="closeButton" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource CaptionButtonStyle}" Width="35" Height="19" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" Background="Red" Command="{x:Static Fluent:RibbonWindow.CloseCommand}">
            <Image Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" Source="{DynamicResource ImageCaptionButtonClose}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
          </Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

I tried lots of stuff (like putting Automation Id) but none worked. Am I looking at wrong portion of code?

Can somebody help in putting Automation UI or Name in the Close Button or some changes through why I can solve the problem? The only requirement is Close, Maximize, Minimize button of the application should be identified by UI Automation tool.

Regards

Comment: Any solution? I have reported this to Codeplex also but no reply yet.

Answer (score 0):

This won't help you identify the buttons, but you could try sending the standard keyboard shortcuts to the window to actually perform the actions:

```
//close the window
Keyboard.SendKeys(myWindow, "{F4}", ModifierKeys.Alt);
```

Comment: I can close the application differently also like: File -> Exit. But my requirement is to identify the Ribbon Window's Close, Maximize and Minimize buttons by the Automation tool with some Automation UID or Name. So, the click on close button should work by automation tool like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Automation Spy](http://www.automationspy.com) for a second check. If UI Automation doesn't give you anything you can try sending (see [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) Win32 messages like WM_CLOSE to the control window and you can use [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) function with parameter SW_MAXIMIZE, SW_MINIMIZE.